# Are multiple document roots to serve the same path possible?

Tags: apache

Is it possible to have a directory structure on an Apache server similar to this:

```
└── www
    ├── root1
    │   └── doc1.html
    └── root2
        └── doc2.html
```

such that doc1.html and doc2.html are both served on the same path?
 (e.g. `http://localhost/doc1.html` and `http://localhost/doc2.html` both result in successful requests?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with aliasing. See httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias